# Connecting to an RDS from an EC2 on different subnets without NAT

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have an RDS instance running on one subnet without NAT, and an EC2 instance running on another subnet with an Internet Gateway configured, both located in the same VPC. I have configured the RDS instance to not be publicly accessible.

I am using the following command in my remote EC2 (running on the second subnet) to connect to the RDS instance:

```
mysql -h xxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root -p
```

I have entered the correct password which I have set when configuring the RDS, but I get the following error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on xxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely need to open port 3306 in the security group assigned to the RDS server. In particular, create a rule allowing ingress on port 3306, and for the source use the ID of the security group assigned to the EC2 server.

Comment: The inbound port 3306 is open. Does 'inbound' apply only to the subnet itself or to the whole VPC?

Comment: What did you open it to? All traffic? If so it applies to the whole VPC. I just checked your question again, are you sure `root` is the correct account? You don't get access to the `root` database account on RDS instances.

Comment: When I was configuring the RDS in the console it asked me for a username, I chose `root`. The problem is that it is not returning a wrong username or password error, I am simply getting a `could not connect` error from MySQL after waiting for a few of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The Security Group ingress rules for your subnet and/or your PostgreSQL instance must have port 3306 open for PostgreSQL. If you have changed the default port, you must use that port instead.

Your EC2 instance should not have to communicate through the internet to reach it, it just needs the proper port open in the security groups.

If you are not allowing all egress data in your EC2 security group, then you will need to ensure egress port 3306 is open on the EC2 security group, to the RDS security group.

Comment: These are my [acl configuration](http://i.imgur.com/2NXP4mL.png) and [security groups configuration](http://i.imgur.com/SXkE0ed.png). As you can see the ports on the security group are set as you mentioned. Is there something I am missing?